# Why a block invoked by a Module can't modify objects from implementing classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module, enumerable

I have some data saved in deeply nested Hashes and Arrays and I have run into trouble with the text encoding of the data. I know for fact that the texts are encoded in "UTF-8", so I decided to go over each element and force the encoding.

So, I created a method called `deep_each` for the `Enumerable` module:

```
module Enumerable
  def deep_each(&block)
    self.each do |element|
      if element.is_a? Enumerable then
        element.deep_each(&block)
      else
        block[element]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And expected to be able to fix the data using the following method call:

```
deephash.deep_each {|element| element.force_encoding("UTF-8") if element.class == String}
```

But the result was disappointing:

```
deephash.deep_each {|element| element.force_encoding("UTF-8") if element.class == String}

> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
> from (pry):16:in `force_encoding'
```

Then I moved the function down the hierarchy, to the "Array" and "Hash" classes:

```
class Hash
  def deep_each(&block)
    self.each do |element|
      if [Array, Hash].include? element.class then
        element.deep_each(&block)
      else
        block[element]
      end
    end
  end
end

class Array
  def deep_each(&block)
    self.each do |element|
      if [Array, Hash].include? element.class then
        element.deep_each(&block)
      else
        block[element]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Surprisingly, the same call works now.

What constraint am I violating here, and how can I define a method for all Enumerables without defining it for every single one of them?

Comment: In the first case you're trying to modify the hash keys (as well as values)

Comment: @FrederickCheung Can you please explain? If you are referring to the use of `each_value` vs. `each` methods, then I don't think this is the problem. `each` works equally in the second snippet, while it does not work for the first snipper (in Enumerator method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you should get the exact same error with both your Enumerable version and your Array/Hash monkey patch. I do. Are you sure you're using the same `deephash` in both cases?

Normally when you loop `each` on a hash, you'd pass in both key and value to the block. You're passing a single value `element` to the block. This then is an Array with the key and value:

```
irb> {a:1, b:2}.each {|el| puts el.inspect }
[:a, 1]
[:b, 2]
```

Your `deep_each` checks if this is an Enumerable, and it is, so it calls `deep_each` on the list. Then, finally, you reach the leafs and call the block on the key and the value. The block checks if it's working with a String, and if so, forces encoding.

If your hash key is a string, you will try to mutate it. But hash keys are frozen, and so `RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String` is raised.

```
irb> {a: {b: {c: "abc"}}}.deep_each { |el| el << "efg" if String === el}
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>"abcefg"}}}}
irb> {a: {b: {"c" => "abc"}}}.deep_each { |el| el << "efg" if String === el}
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

Comment: You are totally right. I found the mistake. The secret was here: `deephash.deep_each {|element| element.force_encoding("UTF-8") if (element.class == String and element.encoding != Encoding::UTF_8)}`. I had modified the block in the midway, checking for the current encoding of the strings before imposing a new encoding on them. Since Hash keys are  UTF-8 by default, no error was reported. Finally, it looks like writing the method for each class separately makes more sense. For the Hash I need to use `each_value` rather than `each`.

Comment: @retrography, You can keep the single method in Enumerable--but rather than using a bunch if-else statements checking for types, you can create a Hash of type/iterator pairs.  See the bottom of my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "\xE2\x82\xAC" #Euro sign in UTF-8
puts str.encoding  #=> UTF-8
puts str  #=> Euro sign in a UTF-8 enabled terminal window

File.open('data.txt', 'w:utf-8') do |f|
  f.write("#{str}\n")
end

Encoding.default_external = 'ISO-8859-1'
str = File.read('data.txt') 
puts str.encoding  #=> ISO-8859-1

arr = [
  {a: str},
  {b: 'world'},
]

arr[0][:a].force_encoding('utf-8')
puts arr[0][:a].encoding  #=> UTF-8
puts arr[0][:a]  #=> Euro sign in a UTF-8 enabled terminal window
```

It would be more illustrative if you posted an example of:  *I have run into trouble with the text encoding of the data*

> Finally, it looks like writing the method for each class separately
>   makes more sense. For the Hash I need to use each_value rather than
>   each

You can do something like this:

```
iterator_for = Hash.new(:each)  #When a non-existent key is looked up, return :each

iterator_for.update({
  Hash => :each_value,
})

data = [
  %w{ hello world goodbye },
  {"a" => "red", "b" => "blue"},
]

data.each do |element|
  element.send(iterator_for[element.class]) do |x|
    puts x
  end

  puts '-' * 20
end

--output:--
hello
world
goodbye
--------------------
red
blue
--------------------
```